# Matplotlib zoom-in-rectangle: drawing across subplots/outside axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

is there a way to create a zoom-in-rectangle that draws across subplots or outside the axis? The current matplotlib navigation zoom-in-rectangle allows you to click and drag the rectangle within one axis at a time, but I want the option to extend the dash rectangle wherever the mouse is.

Comment: No it's not possible by default. I guess the main reason this has not been implemented because it's completely unclear what should happend if you zoom across different subplots.

Comment: So just drawing across the subplots is not possible? I'm not interested in making it zoom in, i'm just interested in drawing that rectangle as I click and drag.

Comment: I think that would be possible. But what purpose would it have?

Comment: Well, I embedded my subplots into a QtGui.MainWindow, and tried to draw a rectangle on a click and drag (drawing as you drag not until the very end of update() ). Then I ask this question to see if it's possible to extend that zoom-in-rectangle across the subplots. I have no problem registering which suplots included in the click and drag, just drawing the rectangle as I drag. The purpose is to let the users know the area they drawn visually, but the functionality (which is implemented) is to make a popup window of the the subplots included in that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea can be to create a new axes which fills the entire figure and make it transparent. You can then use a rectange selector for that axes.

[image]

```
from matplotlib.widgets import RectangleSelector
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,2)
for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.scatter(np.random.rand(7), np.random.rand(7), c=np.random.rand(7))

def select(eclick, erelease):
    x1, y1 = eclick.xdata, eclick.ydata
    x2, y2 = erelease.xdata, erelease.ydata
    pass

overax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
overax.patch.set_alpha(0)
overax.axis("off")

rs = RectangleSelector(overax, select,
                       drawtype='box', useblit=True,
                       button=[1, 3],
                       minspanx=5, minspany=5,
                       spancoords='pixels',
                       interactive=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow, perfect! Thank you.

Comment: What about if I want to draw on each subplots?